# Should This Question be Closed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, scope

The author of this question ([Is software testing actually done on professional projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702604/is-software-testing-actually-done-on-professional-projects-closed)) questions whether it should have been closed. I feel it's  a discussion, and so doesn't belong on a Q&A site. How do others feel about it?

Comment: Thanks John. You've put in a lot of effort with my question.

Comment: @Robert: you're welcome. Your question should almost have been migrated to meta, as most of the comments actually belong here, and not on SO (where I expect they'll be deleted along with your question).

Comment: It looks to me like an amazingly bad fit with SO.  It belongs on a discussion site, where (among other things) answers are listed in chronological order.  Answer threads would also be nice.

Comment: For posterity, it was reopened Sept. 14, 2010 at 6:06 pm PDT.

Comment: Shouldn't *this* question be closed?

Answer (score 7):

It's clearly a discussion/opinion question (asking people about their personal experience, which means there are no wrong answers) *and* a multi-part question of the most heinous variety.

Kick it to the curb.

Comment: Personal opinions are quite often asked on SO. Especially when people evaluate some products/libraries/technologies. In my case it's software testing. Nonetheless opinions were expected I agree on that. But of experienced fellow developers.

Comment: @Robert: if I see a "personal opinion" question, I vote to close it.

Comment: @Robert: Asking for opinions "of experienced fellow developers" is still asking for opinions, which doesn't work very well on a Q&A site.  It's not important *who* you're asking, it's important *what* you're asking *for*.  In this case, you're asking for statements that can't be objectively verified or ranked.  That belongs on a discussion forum or someplace where the objective isn't to establish correctness/usefulness of answers.

Answer (score 6):

Belongs on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: We really should have an official migration path to that site.

Comment: Isn't Programmers still in beta? To me it sounds like it doesn't have a top notch community... As of yet...

Comment: While the subject matter is Programmers.SE material, I'm pretty sure it'd be closed there as *not a real question* as well. I don't think any SE site accepts position papers with multiple questions as an acceptable question. The short of it is that the question needs to be split up and the rant at the top removed.

Comment: But how would you tackle question relations. these questions are clearly related. Answering one could interfere with others and not provide decent answers without "the bigger picture". I admit I also wanted people to take the questionnaire to collect some data for my thesis. But I wouldn't be able to ask all those questions on SO anyway. At least not in a measurable & structured manner.

Comment: @Robert, I think you misunderstand what Stack Overflow is for: if you have a specific question for which you need a definitive answer, you're in the right place. It's not a survey site, or a place to launch guided questionnaires.

Comment: @Robert: If you want the questions to be related then link from one to the other.  It'll even show up in the "linked" sidebar on the right.  That's a lot more effective than asking multi-parters and you're more likely to get decent answers.

Comment: @Mark Trapp: I don't think I misunderstood what SO is for. I guess my reputation shows that as well. But I haven't completely grasped the narrowing of the rules over time. Obviously. Anyways. Thanks for all your input guys.

Comment: @All: I've asked a single question now on Programmers that hopefully goes along with rules. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3824

Answer (score 5):

The fact that there is a table of contents for his numerous questions seems to indicate his question is far too broad, and like you said, would wind up being a discussion. I'd have voted to close it.

Comment: Most of the questions supplied a set of possible answers which would narrow the answers. At least how I thought of it.

Comment: @Robert: It doesn't matter. One question per... question, and it's not acceptable to ask loaded questions (that is, presupposing the answers to your own questions).